# infinite scroll with real-time mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have an issue with my website on infinite scrolling.
My website database is based on real-time mysql, and I need to select the 20 rows of the real-time table each time with infinite scrolling(the table sorts by the update time) but at the same time, the user could insert, delete or update the mysql table and it may disorder the previous order. And it may make the infinite scroll went into a mess, such as data repeating or missing, so what should I do to guarantee the continuity of data.

```
table post
(id int pk,
content varchar,
information varchar,
update_time timestamp)
```

Comment: Show the code(™). Show the table structure.

Comment: doctor I have an issue with my leg, but I'm not going to let you look at it.

Comment: @tim lol, I edited my question again!

Comment: Sir Xiaolun. please where i your code. I mean show your code which indicates what you have tried Like what @tim has stated, someone who has an injury on the leg but does not want her doctor to see it so as to ptrescribe treatment should not be in the hospital in the first place. So as its now there is nothing we can do for you. Show your code and indicate where you are having issues and you will get response from this venerable site. Peace be with you